# Is Atlassian's tutorial diagram for "git pull --rebase" incorrect?

Tags: git

**For anyone reading this now - Atlassian have fixed their diagram.**

---

Orginal question:

I'm reading Atlassian's excellent Git tutorials but I'm confused by one diagram:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull
It's the 3rd flow diagram from the top.

I think it should be just one line: **D - A - B - C - E - F - G**
With "Remote origin/master" pointing at C and "Local master" pointing at G.

My experiments using SmartGit (pull rebase option) and GitHub seem to confirm this answer but it seems more likely I've misunderstood than that Atlassian have made a mistake in their diagram.

They go on say further down: "Many developers prefer rebasing over merging, since it’s like saying, 'I want to put my changes on top of what everybody else has done.'". This statement also seems to contradict the diagram.

If the diagram is right, please explain how to put local changes on top of origin changes so that origin's history is preserved.

Comment: Yeah that diagram doesn't seem right. Local commits E, F and G should be appended after commit remote C. I think you are right. The diagram is wrong.

Comment: The first diagram is wrong too (or wrongly described by the accompanying text), and the statement of what a merge commit is, is completely wrong. I’d say this is not at all a good tutorial. Stop reading it immediately.

Comment: nice catch. You can report it to Atlassian

Comment: @LeGEC I've raised it in the community here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-Atlassian-s-tutorial-diagram-for-git-pull-rebase-incorrect/qaq-p/1441588#M56741 Is that the right way to report it?

Comment: Atlassian have picked it up and are going to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Diagram is **not** correct.

When you pull with the `--rebase` option, all your local commits will be **appended** to the remote branch, thus you are right, that `E-F-G` should be after the remote changes `A-B-C`, leading to `D-A-B-C-E'-F'-G'` (`'` is used to designate that the commits are not technically the same commits as the originals, they are re-written versions of those commits)

Comment: "local changes `A-B-C`"; *remote* changes? Also, consider notation like `D-A-B-C-E'-F'-G'` to indicate the commits that were rewritten.

Comment: @doompickaxe I'm trying to check with Atlassian but looks like your answer is correct apart from the typo pointed out by Joe. Do you want to edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted? (assuming Atlassian don't point out a misunderstanding)